# TitanDB Drop Everything Including Indexes

Tags: java, titan

I would like to drop everything from TitanDB.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477443/how-to-delete-graph-in-titan-with-cassandra-storage-backend) says that it's possible by removing all the vertices but I am failing to delete the graph with that recommended approach. I can't do `g.V.remove()` in java and when I delete each `Vertex` independently this only gets rid of the vertices but leaves behind the indexes.

Is there a way (from within java) of dropping everything ? 
I am essentially looking for the equivalent of using `cqlsh` and typing:

```
cqlsh> DROP KEYSPACE titan;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick to the Titan tools, what about the `TitanCleanup` utility?

http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/1.0.0/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/util/TitanCleanup.html

Nuking the C* keyspace will certainly do the trick with great efficiency, though might leave external ("mixed") indexes stranded if you have them.

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Cassandra Java driver to connect to Cassandra and drop the keyspace. Make sure to close the TitanGraph first.